# How to fix problem closing dropdown when I click outside it

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am developing an angular 5 project. My home page is composed by many components. In `navbarComponent` I have a dropdown list.
When the dropdown list is open, on clicking outside it, I would like it to close automatically.

This is my code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.showMenu = false;
}

toggle() {
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
}

<div *ngIf="isConnect" class=" userStyle dropdown-toggle " (click)="toggle()">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu subMenu" role="menu" *ngIf="showMenu">
        <li (click)="profile()" class="subMenuItem"> PROFILE</li>
        <li (click)="administration()" class="subMenuItem subMenuItem-last">ADMINISTRATION</li>
        <li class="subMenuItem subMenuItem-last"><button class="btn blue-btn" (click)="logout()" ><mat-icon mat-list-icon fontIcon="icon-logout"></mat-icon>LOGOUT</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented it in my project. First we need to bind click event on window in `ngOnInit` hook.

```
ngOnInit() : void {
  this.windowClickSubscription = Observable
    .fromEvent(window, "click")
    .subscribe(this.handleWindowClick)
}
```

Now whenever there is a click on window our `this.handleWindowClick` will be called, lets add implementation of this method.

```
handleWindowClick(res: any) {
  let target: any = res.target;
  let threshold: number = 0;
  while(target && target.className != 'grouped-control' && threshold <= 4) {
    target = target.parentElement;
    threshold++;
  }
  if(target && target.className != 'grouped-control') this.hasOptions = false;
}
```

This function will search for parent of event target until it finds `grouped-control` which we need to close when there is a click on window excluding this element. So if we fount that element we do nothing else we close it using `hasOptions` flag.

Finally we need to unbind that event on `ngDestroy`

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.windowClickSubscription && this.windowClickSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Now ofcourse you need to define `this.windowClickSubscription` property in your component and bind reference of component to function `handleWindowClick` in your constructor

**Edit**

To bind reference of constructor add the following line in your constructor

```
constructor() {
  this.handleWindowClick = this.handleWindowClick.bind(this);
}
```

This will allow you to pass this function as callback handler and it will be executed with reference of your component.

Since we can show hide html with help of `*ngIf` I am toggling my control which I need to hide using flag  `this. hasOptions`

Comment: What i do exactly in constructor for handleWindowClick? And in the html part what i do?

Answer (score 0):

When you open Dropdown adds any class like 'open' with class 'dropdown-toggle' and when you close dropdown removes that class. If you click outside the dropdown area it will close the dropdown.

I have achieved using below code

```
<div class="drop-menu">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" title="Filter" (click)="openDropdown()">
       <span class="fa fa-arrow"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu subMenu" role="menu" *ngIf="showMenu">
       <li (click)="profile()" class="subMenuItem"> PROFILE</li>
       <li (click)="administration()" class="subMenuItem subMenuItem-last">ADMINISTRATION</li>
       <li class="subMenuItem subMenuItem-last"><button class="btn blue-btn" (click)="logout()" ><mat-icon mat-list-icon fontIcon="icon-logout"></mat-icon>LOGOUT</button></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Code for component.ts file:

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }
ngOnInit() {
  const selectDOM = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0];
  this.renderer.listen('document', 'click', (evt) => {
    const eventPath = evt.path;
    const hasClass = _.where(eventPath, { className: 'drop-menu' });
    if (hasClass.length <= 0) {
      this.renderer.removeClass(selectDOM, 'open');
    }
  });
}

openDropdown() {
  const selectDOM = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-toggle')[0];
  if (selectDOM.classList.contains('open')) {
    this.renderer.removeClass(selectDOM, 'open');
  } else {
    this.renderer.addClass(selectDOM, 'open');
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a TemplateRef-Id to your menu:

```
<ul #menuRef class="dropdown-menu subMenu" role="menu" *ngIf="showMenu">

                ....
</ul>
```

Get that TemplateRef in Code:

```
@ViewChild('menuRef') menuRef: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Then you have to register a global (on document level) click event:

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
hideMenu(event) {
  if (!this.menuRef.nativeElement.Contains(event.target) {
    if (this.showMenu) {
       this.showMenu = false;
    }
  }
}
```

If the click was outside of your dropdown, you set showMenu=false and your menu closes.

But why not use a component for your dropdown? [ng-select](https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select) does all of that automatically.